# How to collect tuple into separate variables

Tags: scala, tuples

```
def giveMeTuple: Tuple2[String, String] = {
    Tuple2("one", "two")
}

def testFive: Unit = {
    val one, two = giveMeTuple
    println(one)
    println(two)
    ()
}

testFive
```

Produces:

```
(one,two)
(one,two)
```

But I was expecting:

```
one
two
```

What is going on with the initialization of `one` and `two`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there.
This is what you need:

```
val (one, two) = giveMeTuple
```

With

```
val one, two = giveMeTuple
```

you are saying: initialize `one` with value returned by `giveMeTuple` and initialize `two` value returned by `giveMeTuple` (in this case `giveMeTuple` will be called twice)

Another similar example is

```
val one, two = 1
```

where both will be initialized to value `1`

Instead you want to *deconstruct* the value return by `giveMeTuple` and take the first and second values from the tuple. In that case `giveMeTuple` will be called only once of course.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That means, declaring several variables will use the right value to initialize all variables? Does that mean that the right side will be executed several times, or that the return value will be copied, or that several references to a single value will be created?

Comment: Yes, for example if you do `val one, two = 1`, both will have value `1`.
And the right side will be executed several times.

Comment: Ok. I assume that when using the tuple assignment syntax `val (one, two) = ...` the right side will be executed only once, which is what I want (right side can be expensive in my case)

Comment: Yes. I've changed my answer

Answer (score 2):

You're missing parenthesis:

```
val (one, two) = giveMeTuple
```

If we decompile the code above, we'll see that this is just the Tuple Pattern which is part of Scalas Pattern Matching feature:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {                                                                                              
  private[this] val x$1: (String, String) = (TupleTest.this.giveMeTuple: (String, String) @unchecked) match { 
    case (_1: String, _2: String)(String, String)((one @ _), (two @ _)) => scala.Tuple2.apply[String, String](one, two)              
  };                                                                                                                                 
  val one: String = x$1._1;                                                                                                          
  val two: String = x$1._2;                                                                                                          
  ()
}
```

While your example is double invocation of the same method and assignment to a fresh value:

```
def giveMeTuple: (String, String) = scala.Tuple2.apply[String, String]("one", "two"); 
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {                                               
   val one: (String, String) = TupleTest.this.giveMeTuple;                             
   val two: (String, String) = TupleTest.this.giveMeTuple;                             
   ()                                                                                  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. So counter-intuituve ... I am coming from Python.

Comment: @delavnog I elaborated a bit to show how tuple deconstruction actually works in Scala